# Executing a C++ code in directories with specific name through bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, c++

I have a directory, named `test`, with 10 folders, named `folder1`, `folder2`, etc., and each folder has  subfolders named `trial01`, `trial02`, `trial03`. Now I have a master C++ file, named `mastercfile.cpp`, outside `test`, which looks like this:

```
$ cd work/
$ ls
test mastercfile.cpp
```

Now I want a bash script that runs this `mastercfile.cpp` into each `trial0y` directory inside `work/test/folderx/trial0y/` in a `for` loop such that it goes into all `trial0y` directories of the 10 folders without copying the C++ file into the trial folder.

I tried using `for` and `find` commands, but I couldn't do it as I am a newbie. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you at least include single example of the desired action ?

Comment: Yes, please show us i) the actual folder structure (run `tree work/test` and add the output to your question; make sure to use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code). ii) The _exact_ command you want to run. `.cpp` files are normally source code, not executable. Do you want to compile it in the different directories? Have you already compiled it and want to execute the compiled binary? What would the input be? What _exactly_ needs to be executed?